# What is the relationship of doInBackground() and process()?

Tags: java, swingworker

Good day. Could you explain the relationship between the two? I'm trying to do a program that uses `SwingWorker`. And I thought that the `publish(value)` is just to pass the `value` to `process()`?

EDIT:

```
class PrimeNumbersTask extends
         SwingWorker<List<Integer>, Integer> {
     PrimeNumbersTask(JTextArea textArea, int numbersToFind) {
         //initialize
     }

     @Override
     public List<Integer> doInBackground() {
         while (! enough && ! isCancelled()) {
                 number = nextPrimeNumber();
                 publish(number);
                 setProgress(100 * numbers.size() / numbersToFind);
             }
         }
         return numbers;
     }

     @Override
     protected void process(List<Integer> chunks) {
         for (int number : chunks) {
             textArea.append(number + "\n");
         }
     }
 }

 JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
 final JProgressBar progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
 PrimeNumbersTask task = new PrimeNumbersTask(textArea, N);
 task.addPropertyChangeListener(
     new PropertyChangeListener() {
         public  void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
             if ("progress".equals(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                 progressBar.setValue((Integer)evt.getNewValue());
             }
     }
 });

 task.execute();
 System.out.println(task.get()); //prints all prime numbers we have got
```

Saw this code from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html

I would like to know, `chunks` is a `List` right? So, how does the `SwingWorker` adds value to it?

Comment: Yeah. But when? Because I can't predict the size of `chunks`.

Comment: You can't. It's up to SwingWorker to decide when it actually notifies the GUI of changes. This is explained in the javadoc. Read it: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish-V...-

Comment: So for example, I did this: `publish("Abc"); publish("Def"); publish("Ghi");` the `chunk.size()` would be different?

Comment: Yes, it might be. There is an example in the link that JB Nizet posted. Did you read it?

Comment: doInBackground is run in a background thread, not the EDT. Process is called within the context of the EDT to allow you to process information passed to the publish method. There is no guarantee when process will be called after publish has ben called. SwingWork queues the items passed through the publish method so that, at some time in the future, they can be passed to process (essentially removed from the queue and given to you), this is why publish doesn't have require a single value to be passed in, but takes a List